# TapeEquilibrium - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, big-o

I'm studying through Codility and I'm doing [this](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/tape_equilibrium/) lesson.

So the basically solution that I thought at first time was:

```
#SOLUTION 1
def solution(A):

    diff = []
    for x in range(1,len(A)):
        first_half = sum(A[:x])
        second_half = sum(A[x:])
        diff.append(abs(first_half - second_half))
    return min(diff)
```

I scored 100% in 'Correctless' but 0% in 'Performance'.

So I thought that maybe my problem was something with diff.append inside my loop.

Then I tried to use a List Comprehension like that:

```
#SOLUTION 2
def solution(A):

    result = min((abs(sum(A[:x]) - sum(A[x:])) for x in range(1,len(A))))
    return result
```

I also tried to remove min() and abs() from my loop, so I tried use pure math:

```
#SOLUTION 3
def solution(A):

result = [sum(A[:x]) - sum(A[x:]) if (sum(A[:x]) - sum(A[x:])) > 0 else sum(A[:x])*-1 - sum(A[x:])*-1 for x in range(1,len(A))]
return abs(min(result))
```

But again, I received a 0% of performance. All the solutions has a **O(N * N)**.

So probably my problem is in use sum( ) inside a loop... what is the best way to improve the performance of my code?

PS: This is not a duplicated question, the problem it's the same of others questions about that Lesson on Codility, but my solution it's different. And I also prefer to use pure Python for that solution, if possible.

Comment: The time complexity is the culprit as you've received.  Try to think another approach to make it `O(n)` possibly?

Comment: You should also include the prob. description here, not a `link` - since it may got out-of-date.

Comment: Thanks @DanielHao! the approach that I'm trying right now Is not call abs() and min() inside the loop... let's see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this approach to see if you got some improvements in performance?   (Just test it and all passed with *flying colors* as well)

This should be just `O(n)` as we move along the list with each loop indexing the *head and tail.*

```
def solution(A):
    heads = A[0]
    tails = sum(A[1:])

    diff = abs(heads - tails)

    for index in range(1, len(A)-1):
        heads += A[index]
        tails -= A[index]
        if abs(heads -tails) < diff:
            diff = abs(heads - tails)
    return diff
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. An way to minimize the sum() use inside my loop. Tks a lot!

Comment: BTW - you also use `lots` of `list slicing` in the loop to sum them.  That's prob. hurts.

Comment: I didn't knew that hurts performance.. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Codility - Gives 100% on Task Score, Correctness and Performance:

```py
from itertools import accumulate

def solution(A):
    x = list(accumulate(reversed(A)))[::-1]
    out = min(abs(a - b) for a, b in zip(accumulate(A), x[1:]))
    return out
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to solve the problem, I'm looking for a way to improve my solution. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy solution using Python it gave 100%

```
def solution(A):
    # Implement your solution here
    total = sum(A[0:len(A)])
    left_sum = A[0]
    right_sum = total-left_sum
    minium = abs(right_sum-left_sum)
    for i in range(1,len(A)-1):
        left_sum = left_sum + A[i]
        right_sum = total-left_sum
        if minium > abs(right_sum-left_sum):
            minium = abs(right_sum -left_sum)
    return(minium)
```